# camera and file callbacks not working cordova 3.3

Tags: android, file-upload, plugins, cordova, callback

Cordova 3.3 callbacks suddenly stopped working. I have had some problem with the plugins from cordova after upgrading from 2.9 to 3.3. After getting everything to work again, by removing every phonegap plugin, and build the project just with cordova command lines. However, now some of the plugins stop working again. See my code below

```
$("#getPicture").click(function(){
        navigator.camera.getPicture(gotPic, failHandler,
            {quality:45, destinationType:navigator.camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
             sourceType:navigator.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY, targetWidth: 270,   targetHeight: 270});
});

function gotPic(data) {
 alert("in got pic") // doesn't get executed even if I set a timeout there
}

function failHandler(e){
  alert("in fail"); // same as above.
}
```

I got the same error when I request the file system

```
 window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.TEMPORARY, 0, gotFS, fail);
      function gotFS(fileSystem) {
    // create false before
    alert("in gotFS");
     fileSystem.root.getFile(src, {create: false}, gotFileEntry, fail);
 }

 function gotFileEntry(fileEntry) {
    alert("in entry");
     fileEntry.file(gotFile, fail);
 }

 function gotFile(file){
    alert("in gf");
    readDataUrl(file);
 }

 function readDataUrl(file) {
     var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onloadend = function(evt) {
        alert("inside onloaded");
        base = evt.target.result;
        alert("base " + base);
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);

 }

 function fail(error) {
    alert(error.code);
 }
```

This have worked perfectly before, and I can't understand why it stopped now. Since I have struggled with getting the plugins working before, I tried to remove the three plugins I though messed it all up.

```
cordova plugin rm org.apache.cordova.camera
cordova plugin rm org.apache.cordova.file-transfer
cordova plugin rm org.apache.cordova.file
```

The two first plugins got removed without any problem, but when I tried to remove the file plugin I got: 
     Deleting plugin org.apache.cordova.file
     No dangling plugins to remove.

And when I run cordova plugins ls, the plugin is still there.

Comment: file is a dependency of file-transfer plugin, so maybe file is automatically removed when you remove file-transfer? The question is why do you remove the plugin if you want to use it?

Comment: I thought I needed to add the plugin again. However, I found my mistake. I had included <script src="cordova.js"/> two times. Didn't realize that it have anything to say..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my problem. Since I'm including the facebook coonect plugin into my application, I had included cordova.js two times. By removing the one, everything was back to normal